# Roshei Teivos in Kli Yekar

Tags: hebrew, pentateuch-chumash

עד עלות חמ"ס

What does  חמ"ס stand for? If it's just the word 'violence', why the ''?
Context:
ויבא עמלק וילחם עם ישראל ברפידים. בילקוט מסיק שעמלק דומה לזבוב כו', משל למלך שהקיף כרם כו', ביאור המשל וסברתו הוא על דרך שכתבנו למעלה בפר' בראשית על פסוק לפתח חטאת רובץ (ד ז) שהיצה"ר המשילוהו רז"ל (ברכות סא.) לזבוב שכח פיו חלוש לעשות נקב בבשר השלם אך במקום שהזבוב מוצא איזו מורסא או שחין אשר שם פתח פתוח קצת לבשר שם ירבץ וירחיב הפרצה, כך היצה"ר אין לו כח להזדווג אצל הצדיק השלם בכל מעשיו ולא פתח לו כלל פתח לחטאת ולנדה, אך הבא לטמא ועושה פתחים לו, שם ירבץ להרחיב הפרצה עד עלות חמ"ס גבר לאין מרפא, וארז"ל (יומא לט.) אל תטמאו בכל אלה. אדם מטמא עצמו מעט מטמאים אותו הרבה כו', ושם הארכנו לדבר מזה כי שם מקומו.

Answer (score 6):

The " mark does not always signify an abbreviation, sometimes it functions like italics, pointing out a play on words. In this case, my guess is the Kli Yakar is combining two pesukim and changing the spelling of a word:

> וַיִּהְיוּ מַלְעִבִים בְּמַלְאֲכֵי הָאֱלֹהִים וּבוֹזִים דְּבָרָיו וּמִתַּעְתְּעִים בִּנְבִאָיו **עַד עֲלוֹת חֲמַת** יְהֹוָה בְּעַמּוֹ עַד **לְאֵין מַרְפֵּא**. (Chronicles II 36:16)
>
> כִּי קִנְאָה **חֲמַת גָּבֶר** וְלֹא יַחְמוֹל בְּיוֹם נָקָם  (Proverbs 6:34)

Combining the words in bold gives עד עלות חמת גבר לאין מרפא. But the Kli Yakar is talking about sin, not anger, so he changes the spelling to חמס which often means sin.

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't seen this explicitly, in the context of what Kli Yakar is discussing it could be a Roshei-Teivot for: (**ח**שך-**מ**וחא-**ס**תימא). See [Tikkunei Zohar 115b](https://www.sefaria.org/Tikkunei_Zohar.115b.1?vhe=Tikkunei_Zohar&lang=bi) which explains that this is the source and root of the Yetzer HaRah like G-d explained to Kayin after he murdered his brother, Hevel ([Bereshit 4:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.4.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

And in this context, see also [Bereshit 32:25-33](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.32.25-33?lang=bi&aliyot=0) and the struggle between Yaacov Avinu and the Angel of Death.

Comment: Interesting. It would fit in context if true (above my pay grade), so the question is would the Kli Yakar expect his readers to know that.

Comment: @N.T. As a product of both Rabbi Shlomo Luria and Shalom Shachna, I would be inclined to think yes. As I was reflecting on this question, another interesting connection occurred. It is a similar language to what is used in regard to Noach and what precipitated the flood. וַתִּשָּׁחֵ֥ת הָאָ֖רֶץ לִפְנֵ֣י הָֽאֱלֹהִ֑ים וַתִּמָּלֵ֥א הָאָ֖רֶץ חָמָֽס׃